# How to display exact error for failed Azure DevOps Pipeline in summary?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-pipeline

I am using Azure DevOps pipeline to run my automation test cases.
I am facing an issue that whenever my test run task fails, it doesn't display me the exact error that why the task failed, it just displays "cmd.exe exited with code '1' " for all test lists in the Summary section and the email.
Is there a way I can recieve the information that which test case failed and why in the summary section and email?
[image: Email Screeshot]

[image: Pipelien Summary Result]

I have 5 cmd tasks in my pipeline, each of them has same configuraion, just the test list name is different.

1. [image: CMD Task 1]
2. [image: CMD Task 2]
3. [image: CMD Task 3]

Comment: You should post the content of your task

Comment: Sorry, what content?

Comment: I assume you have 3 command line tasks in your pipeline …

Comment: Updated the task screenshot.

Comment: So it is an on premise azure devops? If so, try calling ArtOfTest ... on this machine on the commandline, when you got it working fix your azure devops task. If you're using azure devops service in the cloud, there won't be a path like C:/Program Files ....